# Wireframe / mesh visible in shadows of render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, normals, wireframe

Blender 3.3.1 LTS / Cycles

I have a human model with:

- multiple particle systems,
- collision
- rigged with metarig
- Corrective shapekeys (top lids only)
- wigcap with baked hair dynamics (copied mesh and cutout the scalp for the head hair)

I have follow a previous project file (that had no problems).

For some reason, this model (only in the render) is showing a mesh or wire frame in the shadow area.

I've tried selecting all the verts in *Edit Mode* and *Merging by Distance*, with no effect.

I have checked the normals – all good

In a version of this file before, I added movement to the rig and collision, this isn't visible.[image: Shader node tree]

[image: Rendered image]

[image: Normals check]

Comment: The mesh on the rendered image doesn't match the mesh on the other images so it looks as if it's being applied to the rendered result as part of the texture. What does the node tree look like in shading layout?

Comment: Thanks John, yes that puzzled me too. 
I've added the shader node tree in the post above – there is a fair bit of displacement going on but this didnt effect my previous model.

Comment: Oh wow! I just double check this all and its the displacment maps going to the volume instead of the displacement in the mat output!

Thanks for mentioning that John!

Comment: You're welcome, but see my comment to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @johnEason in the comments, the wireframe and render issue (mesh) dont match and prompted my attention to the shader nodes.

After double checking, you'll see in the image attached above the displacement map is going to the **Volume** material output, rather than the **Displacement**

This being corrected – the problem is now solved!

[image: Solved shader issue][image: No lighting render][image: render]

Comment: I hope that should read "the problem is **now** solved" rather than "the problem is **not** solved"! :^))